# Crucible REST communication with token fails (401 not authorized)

Tags: java, rest, atlassian-crucible

I'm trying to work with tokens to access a project in crucible via REST, but I'm getting an 401 error that says i'm not authorized.

First, i'm generating a token like this:

```
http://host:8060/rest-service/auth-v1/login?userName="+username+"password="+password
```

The token is generated successfully. I save it in a string `loginToken`.

After this, i try to access a project with this token like this:

```
responseItems = myClient.OpenRead("http://host:8060/rest-service/reviews-v1?FEAUTH=" + loginToken + "/"+project+"/reviewitems");
```

Unfortunatly this fails. The error says i'm not authorized (401). If i try the same in my browser (generating the token, then using the token to access the project) it works. I already found out that doing this in the browser additionally generates a cookie which the browser uses for further authentification. I don't even need to use a correct token anymore...

How can i accomplish this in Java?